# Error while Importing MySQL dump into Aurora

Tags: mysql, rds, amazon-aurora

I took a dump of my RDS MySQL database(5.7) with utf8 as character set and collation. Intent is to migrate the database to Aurora 5.6. During the import, I see an error where it complains about the query being incorrect. Now this is the dump file that mysql generated so my guess is that its having problem inserting the data in question. I checked for that data string in the dump and it does exist but I see nothing wrong in it. Here's the error I get during import. Any pointers ?

```
 ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near ''2352eb05-7596-3' at line 1
```

Comment: Perhaps the error message is right and you have a syntax error. Why don't you verify the query?

Comment: What is the full query that contains that string? The fact that your error shows `''` together makes me think it has an unescaped apostrophe inside a quoted string.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Migrate.html

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yup I did verify the query, nothing wrong there.